# Ubuntu 11.10, kernel 3.0.0-17 Booting problem "Hangs"

Tags: 11.10

I've update the kernel from 3.0.3-16 to kernel 3.0.0-17 but it hangs after after giving starting Lightdim [OK]
while its installed on vaio VGN-FZ340E [32 bit] SSD hard disk and the graphic card is Nvidia GeForce 8400M GT and the driver is the latest version which is 295.33

Any one can give me a help please

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [How to report a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Regards,

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Instead of editing your question title, please mark the solution which resolved your question as accepted by clicking the checkmark icon to the left of it. This way, the system and other users know it has been properly resolved and which solution worked for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It happen to me too. I solve mine by editing the GRUB loader and setting to boot on VT=3 the once booted on terminal. I re-install the Nvidia driver downloaded from Nvidia website.

Comment: Thanks it works I reinstalled the Nvidia driver and it works